# How to Add Tapped List item to Favorite_Item_Page

Tags: flutter, favorites

I have this piece of code. It contains a list of countries with a favorite icon in front of each list tiles. I want the tapped text to save/unsave in Favorite_Page. I tried this many times but could not get what I really want to do. Please explain the whole code if possible.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    void main() => runApp(MyApp());
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Favorite Item"),
            ),
            body: FavoriteScreen(),
          ),
          initialRoute: '/',
          routes: {
            '/': (ctx) => FavoriteItem(),
          },
        );
      }
    }
    class FavoriteItem extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _FavoriteItemState createState() => _FavoriteItemState();
    }
    class _FavoriteItemState extends State<FavoriteItem> {
      static final List<String> countryList = [
        'India',
        'America',
        'Australia',
        'Russia',
        'Japan',
        'China',
        'Nepal',
      ];
      List<bool> _isFavorited = List.filled(countryList.length, false);
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: countryList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  countryList[index],
                ),
                trailing: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () =>
                      setState(() => _isFavorited[index] = !_isFavorited[index]),
                  icon: _isFavorited[index]
                      ? Icon(Icons.favorite)
                      : Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: it is correctly changing between favorite and favorite_border icons.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm French so I have probably made some mistakes in my answer : sorry)

This piece of code just initialize a list of country. The list `_isFavorited` is filled with false at the beginning. That's mean that by clicking on an element, you just set to true the element at the position of the country in _isFavorited. I will explain with an example, with the list of country ['Japan','USA",'France'], _isFavorited = [false,false,false]. If I click on USA, _isFavorited will be equal to [false,true,false]. Your piece of code is saving this but not the text as you requested..

You may try this :

```
 List <String> _isFavorited=[];
 ...
 setState(){
    if (_isFavorited.contains(countryList[index])){
       _isFavorited.remove(country[index]);
    }else{
       _isFavortied.add(country[index]);
    }
 }
```

As a result, you might have a list called _isFavorited filled with name of country you liked. You can print this list each time you tap on a country to check if it works! Is this what you were looking for ?

I hope it could help you !